# I cannot install libStaticMapPlugin.so file. How can i?

Tags: gazebo-plugin, gazebo-9

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello,

I tried to create a world with satellite images using libStaticMapPlugin.

But i get an error like this:

[Err] [Plugin.hh:180] Failed to load plugin libStaticMapPlugin.so: libStaticMapPlugin.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

than i find the package which keeps plugins and cannot see static map plugin.

I use Gazebo 9 on Ubuntu 18.04

How can i install libStaticMapPlugin?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/26769/i-cannot-install-libstaticmapplugin.so-file.-how-can-i?/) by [HarunBerk](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/45618/harunberk/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 16 on 2021-04-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Firstly, thanks for your answers.

I have already searched for the plugin in that folders but it was not exist.

@BillThePlatypus said "the plugin is for gazebo10" than i think the plugin doesn't exist on gazebo9
https://answers.gazebosim.org//question/23776/gazebo-static-map-plugin-not-loading/

but i saw the repo including the plugin with @Veerachart 's answer.

so, i expected, my system doesn't allowed to install packages from packages.osrfoundation.org.

i watched those steps to get plugin:

1.Setup my computer to accept software from packages.osrfoundation.org.

sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://packages.osrfoundation.org/gazebo/ubuntu-stable `lsb_release -cs` main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/gazebo-stable.list'

2. update packages

sudo apt-get update

3. tried to open gazebo but i have faced with a problem:

gazebo: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgazebo_common.so.9: undefined symbol: _ZN8ignition10fuel_tools12ClientConfig12SetUserAgentERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE

4. upgraded the libraries with

sudo apt upgrade libignition-math2

5. than tried to run gazebo and it worked well

gazebo --verbose static_map_plugin.world

Thanks everyone, these are my experiences. I hope it can help others.

---

Originally posted by [HarunBerk](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/45618/harunberk/) with karma: 16 on 2021-04-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I'm on gazebo11 and I found libStaticMapPlugin.so in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gazebo-11/plugins`. The plugin also exists in the main repo for gazebo-9 (https://github.com/osrf/gazebo/tree/gazebo9/plugins), so I think it should be similar in gazebo-9.

Did you source the setup file (`/usr/share/gazebo-9/setup.sh`) before running? If the output of `echo $GAZEBO_PLUGIN_PATH` doesn't contain the path to the so file, the plugin cannot be found.

---

Originally posted by [Veerachart](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/39778/veerachart/) with karma: 226 on 2021-04-06

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

If you have the libStaticMapPlugin.so file somewhere, you can copy and paste it to `~/your_workspace_ws/devel/lib` folder. Now Gazebo should be able to find it.

---

Originally posted by [bach](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/45513/bach/) with karma: 36 on 2021-04-08

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1